# WCF Service Reference not giving non-async methods

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, asynchronous

I recently made a WCF service in C# and hosted it on a server running IIS 8.

Everything worked perfectly when testing locally and I was able to test all of my methods with success. My issue comes when I try to add a service reference to that WCF service in a separate project, the only methods it exposes at this point are `async` methods even though I never implemented any of my methods as async.

An example of a method would be:

```
public string getName(User user)
{
     return user.name;
}
```

Something as simple as that would work when I tested it in Visual Studio, but when I host it in IIS and try to add a service reference, the only method I can seem to call or have access to is:

```
getNameAsync
```

Why would it do this even though I never implemented it as `async` in the first place? On top of that, I cannot uncheck "generate methods for async" when I add the service reference in the first place.

Any ideas?

Edit: For reference, I am trying to test these methods inside of a Windows 8.1 app that references the service.

Comment: Is your client silverlight?

Comment: did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the code is generated. Normally you will find also and event called GetNameCompleted for which you subscribed in the client code like that (after creating a the method ClientGetNameCompleted):

```
client.GetNameCompleted += ClientGetNameCompleted ;
```

In this method you will use the service result. something like that:

```
private void ClientGetNameCompleted (object sender, GetNameCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result != null)
    {
        // use the e.Result that contains the returned data;
    }
}
```